# Conditional with style tag not working in React

Tags: reactjs

Conditional is not working, because I use that like this

```
var uls = document.querySelectorAll('.menu ul')

function clickEvent(params) {
    var visable = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < menubars.length; i++) {
                menubars[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
                    for (var j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
                        visable = uls[j].visibility;
                        if ((visable === "visible") || (visable === "")) {
                            closeMenu();
                        } else {
                            openMenu();
                        }
                    }
                }, false);
            }
}
```

and warning like this

[image]

Line 33:55:  Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) 'visable', 'visable', 'visable'  no-loop-func

It was working at html. But I moved on React, Click event is not active. So I think using style for conditional. And I found using class tag. But How I can utilize that.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Warning is raised up because you are declaring `visable` outside the closure in which you are using it. Try to move `visable` declaration inside the `addEventListener` function in this way:

```
function clickEvent(params) {
            for (var i = 0; i < menubars.length; i++) {
                menubars[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
                    for (var j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
                        var visable = uls[j].visibility;
                        if ((visable === "visible") || (visable === "")) {
                            closeMenu();
                        } else {
                            openMenu();
                        }
                    }
                }, false);
            }
}
```

This should solve your problem.